# Permissions to Upload images in text field

Tags: 8, media

The Administrator role has no problem with this, but a lesser role (Editor) that I created cannot upload an image in the basic html text box.  They ARE ABLE to upload images as files and images, however.  What is the permission setting that I am overlooking here?
I should mention, this is Drupal 8.

The basic html option does work for uploading in-line images - for the Administrator.  Permissions on the in-line folder are correct.  Allowing my Editor role to use full html and even restricted HTML does not answer.

Just a further note, Editor can insert an in-line image in source code mode.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Full HTML in order to accept upload images in a text box. 
Basic HTML doesn't allow img tag.

The other option is to add img tag in basic Html format, check:

> admin/config/content/formats/manage/basic_html

or create a new text format which will be available to other roles and will allow img tag.

Comment: Nope.  The icon for inserting an image does exist in the Basic HTML format and the Full HTML format, neither of which actually load an image.  The screen advises that something is being loaded but nothing happens.  As I mentioned, it does work (as Basic HTML) when the user has Administration privileges but not with the set of privileges in my invented role of Editor.  I guess it will be trial and error - toggling permissions - to find which one it is.  Thanks